# Django haystack with elasticsearch SearchQuerySet returns None

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have default django user model which i want to index using elasticsearch
I'm using django-haystack.

in **settings.py**

```
HAYSTACK_SEARCH_RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 12
HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor' 
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
            'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
            'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
        },
}
```

in **search_indexes.py**

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True)
    first_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='first_name', null=True)
    last_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='last_name', null=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return User

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

and build the index using `python manage.py rebuild_index`

now in shell

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
SearchQuerySet().all()
```

it returns all the indexed objects (I can confirm the count is same as number of entries in db)

when I do 
`SearchQuerySet().filter(first_name='Wendy')`  It returns two results object which is again as expected.

but when I try  `SearchQuerySet().filter(content='Wendy')`  it returns None.

basically I want to create an API, in which we can pass a query param and return all the user objects that contains this query string in any field.
http://localhost/search/?q=Wendy

This is my first time I'm using Elasticsearch or (anysearch engine with haystack) so I'm not able to understand what is going on.

After little bit search I found few threads on stack overflow which suggests to use `Ngram` or `EdgeNgram` but again those also couldn't work.(I rebuilded the whole index). I even tried `content_auto` in filter but no success.

Any help or lead will be appreciated.
I was following this official docs.
http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#quick-start

PS: I wrote here only two fields (firstname, lastname) but there are couple more fields in my actual code. its just to write here.

PPS: I'm using Django 1.9. could that be an issue?

This is how my view looks like

```
def search_api(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=query)
    data = map(lambda x: x.get_stored_fields(), sqs)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: What does your `user_text.txt` file look like?

Comment: @DerekKwok: I dont have any `user_text.txt`. is it necessary to create? if yes where should I create?

Comment: You defined `text = indexes.CharField(document=True)` without using `use_template=True` parameter, how are you populating data for this field? See http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html

Comment: maybe rebuild index?